# Can we make separately submit the iPhone and iPad version of an app on iTunes store?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, ipad

I am having an iPhone app.

I have converted my iPhone app into an iPad app.

Now I want to submit my app both iPhone and iPad version separately on iTunes store. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, no problem ! That in fact the thing to do if you want different prices for your apps or if you want a users having both iPad and iPhone to buy the application twice.

Just submit the two applications with a different name.  The "HD" suffix is generally used for iPad version of an iPhone/iPod application

Comment: Thanks for your input. :) Can we not use the same name for both iPhone and iPad version? Is it necessary to give different names?

Comment: We need to specify it,otherwise how can we differentiate between two apps on AppStore!!!

Comment: Apple won't let you use a name that already exists even if its yours !

Comment: Isn't that answer your question ? Why don't you accept it or at least up vote ?

Comment: @VdesmedT : I am Sorry. I forgot to tick your answer as an "Answer" I have done that and also given one up vote. Sorry once again and Thanks for the help :)